# How can I insert source code from Xcode into OpenOffice without getting an paragraph for every single line?

Tags: xcode, formatting, openoffice.org

That's important for good documentation, but currently it just doesnt work well. If I copy source code from Xcode editor into OpenOffice Writer, then every single line is an own paragraph. I have a paragraph style for source code, but because of multiple paragraphs I get a lot of unnecessary spaces.

Could i program a macro that combines these source code paragraphs to a single paragraph, or is there an easy-going way to handle that problem? Maybe some setting in Xcode for text-formatting when copying something to the clopboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if I'm off the mark here but when you go to paste in Open Office, instead of doing a normal paste, ctrl-v, have you tried using ctrl-shif-v? Paste special, and choose unformatted text.

Comment: This does not work, they stay paragraph, even when copying as unformated text.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your paragraph style for source code includes vertical whitespace before or after the paragraph. You just have to remove that whitespace.

Comment: yes, but it shouldn't happen, that I get multiple paragraphs. It should be one single paragraph.

Comment: So you would like to replace End-Of-Paragraph marks with End-Of-Line marks. I suppose this is doable with a macro in OpenOffice. Anyway, nothing is possible from Xcode side.